# Pass a string with quotation marks as variable in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a function that takes multiple string arguments in the form of e.g. `Subscription(items=["A", "B", "C"])` (quotation marks are mandatory, alphabet is just an example here). I don't want to write the arguments manually so I have a loop like

```
string=""
for letter in alphabet.values():
   tmp="\"+letter+"\","
   string=string+tmp

print(string) #only for debugging
Subscription(items=[string])
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, nothing happens. However, if I copy the string printed to the console and paste it into the `items=[ ]`, it works. So the content seems to be fine but I suspect that something about the `\"` formatting seems to be off when pasting the variable. I feel like I made a thinking mistake but I can't figure it out. Does anybody here have an idea?

Comment: do you mean something like: `','.join([f'"{a}"' for a in alphabet.values()])`  ?

Comment: You can mix `'` and `"` to make it easier to make a string with embedded quotes.

Comment: `items=[string] != items=["A", "B", "C"]` The first one will be a list containing one string. The second one is a list containing three different strings

Comment: @warped: This makes the code more smooth (thank you already) but unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: @HampusLarsson: You are right, the variable explorer does show me that it's treated as one big string in the subscription function. I guess this is the problem. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: `["A", "B", "C"]` are not strings "with quotation marks", they are just strings consisting of one character each. The quotation marks are Python syntax to indicate that they are strings, they are not part of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error messages?
Perhaps try something like:

```
string = ""
for letter in alphabet.values():
   tmp = f"\'{letter}\',"
   string = string+tmp

# print(string)
Subscription(items=[string])
```

Trying single quotes and double quotes might help, otherwise make sure that `alphabet.values()` actually returns a list of letters and that check that alphabet is a real module or class.

Comment: The result is the same, unfortunately - nothing happening. No error but also no result. If I take the printed string from the console and paste it into items=[], then it works like a charm. So alphabet.values() itself works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution! The key is to first join them and then split them up again!

```
string=",".join(f'{letter}' for letter in alphabet.values()])
Subscription(items=string.split(","))
```

The split makes the quotation marks unnecessary as it provides a list of strings.

Thanks a lot y'all for your help! :)

Comment: That should be just the same as `items=list(alphabet.values())`, or possibly even `items=alphabet.values()`

Comment: I just tried these two options but none of them works, unfortunately.

Comment: `Subscription(items=list('ABC'))`.  Even `Subscription(items='ABC')` may work as both a list and string are iterable.  You didn't define `alphabet` or `Subscription` so just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this. `.values()` returns a sequence that can be converted directly to a list!

```
items = list(alphabet.values())
Subscription(items=items)
```

Comment: Yes and no. I realized that the example I gave is giving a wrong lead as in the real application, it's not just the letter but something like 'text:{letter}:text' so only alphabet.values() doesn't work.

Comment: @starsnpixel if you can add more detail to the question I can fine tune the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated! Well, basically, it would need to be something like `Subscription(items=['text1:A:text2', 'text1:B:text2', 'text1:C:text2'])` so what's working for me right now is `string=",".join([f'text1:{letter}:text2' for letter in alphabet.values()])`

Comment: @starsnpixel I see by your self answer that you're joining the strings and splitting them again.  That's wasted effort.  Given what you just said, you could use `items=[f'text1:{letter}:text2' for letter in alphabet.values()]`